# Making a 4 digit pin in Angular 2/4 for mobile phones?

Tags: android, ios, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

What have others done for a 4 digit pin? 
I am looking to make a 4 digit pin in Angular 2/4 but there seems to be no easy way to do it, that I have found out yet.

Phones do have a `soft keyboard` that can show only numbers. 
The best way (only way) to show a number keyboard on both android and ios is with the following html tag:

```
<input
    type="number" 
    pattern="[0-9]*" 
    inputmode="numeric" 
    style="-webkit-text-security: disc;"></input>
```

Now that gives me a keyboard that has decimals, dashes, commas, among other things.  I need to make sure only numbers are put in the box. The best way I can think of is catch key press events and remove invalid characters as they are typed. 
There are 3 different ways I have tried and all have flaws:
First is catch the keyup event:

The Html:

```
<input
    (keyup)="checkPin($event)" 
    type="number" 
    pattern="[0-9]*" 
    inputmode="numeric" 
    style="-webkit-text-security: disc;"></input>
```

The Typescript:

```
checkPin($event: KeyboardEvent) {
  console.log($event)
  let value = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;

  if ($event.target) {
    if (value == "") {
      value = value.slice(0, 0);
    }

    if (value.length > 4) {
      value = value.slice(0, 4)
    }
    (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value = value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }
}
```

I do not like this because code because as the key is pushed it can be seen in the box then disappears.

The second approach is to catch the `keypress` event:

The HTML:

```
<input 
  (keypress)="keyPress($event)"
  type="number"
  pattern="[0-9]*"
  inputmode="numeric"
  style="-webkit-text-security: disc;"></input>
```

The Type Script

```
keyPress(event: any) {
  const pattern = /[0-9]/;
  const inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
  let lIsTooLong: boolean = event.target.value.length > 3
  if (!pattern.test(inputChar) ||  lIsTooLong) {
    // invalid character, prevent input
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

This works very well, but it does not work on android when the period or comma is pushed, the period is still put into the input box.

I tried using `input`:

The HTML:

```
<input 
  #myInput
  [(ngModel)]="input"
  (input)="myInput.value = format(input)"
  type="number"
  pattern="[0-9]*"
  inputmode="numeric"
  style="-webkit-text-security: disc;"></input>
```

The Type Script:

```
format(valString) {
  console.log(valString);
  if (!valString) {
    return '';
  }
  let val = valString.toString();
  if (val.length > 4) {
    val = val.slice(0, 4)
  }
  return val.replace(/\D+/g, '')
}
```

This last way seemed promising but when more than two `.` were entered the code actually broke and stopped calling the format function. I did a console log and the value `valString` was and empty string, but the text in the box was `123423.........`

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:

There is an easier way. Using what you originaly used, keyup event:

**HTML**:

```
<input type="number" style="border:1px solid black" (keydown)="onKeyPress($event)" >
```

**Typescript**:

```
onKeyPress(event){
  if (!(event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57)){
        event.preventDefault()
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fdquhi?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

---

The input could be processed thru (input) event where you remove anything not numeric with a regexp. But this method will need two-way binding mechanism. Example:

**HTML**:

```
   <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="input" #myInput style="border:1px solid black" (input)="myInput.value = format(input)">
```

**Typescript**:

```
format(valString) {
    if (!valString) {
        return '';
    }
    let val = valString.toString();
    return val.replace(/\D+/g, '');
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyvtj8?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I tried your demo nothing on a keyboard is working for me right now.

Comment: You mean you cannot enter letters neither numbers?

Comment: It works. But I need to use `type=number` to get the number pad up on an android phone.

Comment: I changed to type="number" and it's working. but I think type="tel" would work also and on mobiles it make show the numeric keyboard

Comment: The update works well. On android `event.preventDefault()` does not work for `.` and `-` which are keycodes `229`. I mean the line of code is called but  the `.` or `-` are still added to the line.

Comment: Yes, I saw the update, thank you for the help. But have you tried the update on an android phone? The comment I made was after I tried the update on my phone, and the results of that test.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is best done using a custom [directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)

The following steps should help you solve your problem:

Generate a new custom directive:
`ng generate directive numberInput`

Then in the generated directive class add this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appnumberInput]'
})
export class NumberInputDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @Input() digitOnly: boolean;

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
    let e = <KeyboardEvent> event;
    if (this.OnlyNumber) {
      if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+C
        (e.keyCode === 67 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+V
        (e.keyCode === 86 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+X
        (e.keyCode === 88 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
          // let it happen, don't do anything
          return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
      }

   @HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
   onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const pastedInput: string = event.clipboardData
    .getData('text/plain')
    .replace(/\D/g, ''); // get a digit-only string
  document.execCommand('insertText', false, pastedInput);
}

@HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
onDrop(event: DragEvent) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const textData = event.dataTransfer
    .getData('text').replace(/\D/g, '');
  this.inputElement.focus();
  document.execCommand('insertText', false, textData);
}

}
  }
```

Then within your template add:

`<input type="text" name="pin" id="pin" placeholder="000" maxlength="4" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" digitOnly>`